# Tar file Extrator programmatically in objective c

Tags: objective-c, tar, tvos

I downloaded tar file in cache folder and I need to extract that file. Is there any way to in tvos .Any library available.Please share the link or code snippet

I tried NVHTarGzip , tar kit etc ... Not at all working

Thanks in advance

Comment: If you can get the content in `.zip` format, that would make it easier for you.  `.tar` is an archaic format.

Comment: https://blog.octo.com/en/untar-on-ios-the-pragmatic-way/ try this one